# Methodology of Choosing Random Data

Tags: statistics

For a project, I have to randomly choose exoplanets out of a database, but since the database has different sections, I have to choose one section. If one section has more exoplanets than another and I am randomly choosing five exoplanets, will the five exoplanets be more diverse if I choose the bigger or smaller section?

Comment: What's your take on this?

Comment: The answer probably depends on the criteria used to sort the exoplanets into sections. If it's other than random then how you make your choice will probably affect a lot more than just how diverse a  sample you get. That said, you might get more useful answers if you delete here and ask at stats.stackexchange.com instead.  If you do, please provide the sorting criteria there.